# Can't find where my mistake is: Majorization of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, majorization

I'm working on the following sequence
$$
u_{n+1} = \sqrt{n+u_n} \text{ with } u_1=1
$$
I've shown that
$$
u_n \leq n
$$
Then
$$
u_{n+1} \leq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{n} \Leftrightarrow \frac{u_{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \sqrt{2}
$$
which I've verified with a python script that it looks true.
But then
$$
u_n = \left(u_{n+1}\right)^2 - n = \left(u_{n+1} - \sqrt{n}\right)\left(u_{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{u_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \left(\frac{u_{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} - 1\right)\left(\frac{u_{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} + 1\right)
$$
Using the result above, then
$$
\frac{u_n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right) = 1
$$
It suggests that $u_n \leq \sqrt{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$ however this is not true and I can't seem to find what mistakes I've done. I'm sure it's just a "stupid" mistake that I can't see somehow, any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{ab}n=\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{n}}\times\dfrac b{\sqrt{n}}$

You actually divided by $n$ not $\sqrt{n}$ so you just get back $\dfrac{u_n}n\le 1$ you know already.